# rails devise only allow existing users to register new users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Is it possible to only allow existing users to register new users? I don't want just anyone to be able to hit the /users/sign_up page, only if you are already logged in. This is an internal app, so all users are trusted to be able to add other users.

Comment: By default, if you are logged in and if you go to `/users/sign_up` you are redirected with the notice that you are already signed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look to the [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem!

Answer (score 0):

You can to using http authentication in your environment. Using the warden

**ApplicationController**

```
before_filter :authenticate_homol

def authenticate_homol
  if (Rails.env == 'staging') # for example
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      username == "login" && password == "123456"
    end
    warden.custom_failure! if performed?
  end 
end
```